# Custom php version when installing LAMP

Tags: customization, php, lamp

Does anyone knows how do we force a php version to be installed when installing lamp via command line? For example I want to php5.1 when installing LAMP.

Comment: [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/109404/582516)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to install PHP 5.1 from repositories.

The [PHP5 Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5) lists supported PHP versions starting from Hardy. 5.2.4 is the first supported version.

You might be able to install from untrusted repositories or compile from source.

But please note **you are taking risks** by *not* using a supported PHP version. The real solution would be to upgrade/fix the application instead of downgrading.

Comment: +1, compile from source is the only option here. Its a really bad idea though.. most security patches in PHP aren't even tested against 5.1 anymore now that 5.2 is the "old version" and 5.3 is the current stable. 5.4 will be out very soon, so you are just slipping further behind.