# How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?

Tags: ppa, php

I am trying to update to install PHP 5.5, 5.6 or 7.0 in Ubuntu 12.04/14.04/16.04 LTS, and I can only get PHP 5.3.10 for Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.5.9 for Ubuntu 14.04 or PHP 7.0.4 for Ubuntu 16.04 using official repositories (using apt-get).

I'm not really sure how to do a manual update – as I need:

- to play around with the new(est) PHP features
- to install older PHP version due support in the software

Comment: if sudo apt-get upgrade Dont upgrade PHP then try sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. For distribution upgrade.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

You could use a PPA to stay up-to-date with PHP or install previous version of PHP (f.e. PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

The most widely used repositories come from Ondřej Surý, the Debian PHP maintainer:

- [ppa:ondrej/php [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php) (for PHP 5.6/7.0/7.1 co-installable versions, PHP 5.5 is no longer supported)

The php5 compat packages:

- [ppa:ondrej/php5-compat [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-compat) (for dummy `php5` to satisfy dependencies in the old packages)

([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

PHP PPAs previously contained Apache 2.4 update.  This is no longer a case, you need to add separate Apache 2.4 repository:

- [ppa:ondrej/apache2 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2) (for Apache 2.4)

If you want use these PPAs, do this:

[ppa:ondrej/php [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php) (for PHP 5.6/7.0/7.1)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php7.1   # for PHP 7.1
sudo apt-get install php7.0   # for PHP 7.0
sudo apt-get install php5.6   # for PHP 5.6
```

To switch between installed versions use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Then you must set Apache to work with right version:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1         # unload the current version
sudo a2enmod  php5.6         # load the version you need
sudo service apache2 restart # restart webserver to apply
```

[ppa:ondrej/php5-compat [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-compat) (for php5 compat)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-compat
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5 # this will pull php5.6 package
```

If you don't have `add-apt-repository` binary do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Precautions:

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)
- Each version of PHP has its own set of modules and `php.ini`.

#### PHP 5.4

Prepackaged latest PHP 5.4 now resides in separate PPA:
[ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable)

Please be aware that PHP 5.4 has reached its end of life on [3. September 2015](https://secure.php.net/eol.php) and it doesn't receive any security updates.  It's recommended to migrate to at least PHP 5.6 that will receive security updated till [31. December 2018](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Installing this PPA works for the most part, but packages that rely on phpapi-20090626+lfs, like php-apc for example, will fail installation as this PPA does not include that particular virtual package. I'm guessing a new PHP version has a new phpapi virtual pacakge, but this is not included if so.

Comment: I ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5` - but when I run `apt-get chanelog php5` it tells me it's still at version 5.3.6. Do I need to specify the PPA in apt-get?

Comment: Turns out you gotta run `sudo apt-get update` first!

Comment: I just asked for php5, and I got php 5.4.0, but it also installed apache 2.2. I did not ask for it, to install apache. I just want php 5.4.0 cli.

Comment: there is the php5-cli package for that!

Comment: Hmm... I wish I could do it all on the CLI... is it possible?

Comment: After adding the ppa, you could do:
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: After installing the ppa, upgrading php and running `php -v`, the version information starts with this error message: _Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory_ Annoying.

Comment: that's normal. Php 5.4 uses a new version of the zend library. When you upgrade to 5.4 the xdebug extension gets recompiled. You need to check inside /usr/lib/php5 the name of the folder. Mine is 20100525, should be yours too, and check if there is a xdebug.so file. Now edit the xdebug.ini file in /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini (or the symlinked /etc/php5/conf.d/**-xdebug.ini) and set the correct path to the xdebug.so file

Comment: There's xdebug package in my PPA together with php5 5.4, so you just need to install it from the PPA.

Comment: Just a forewarning – the repository will be updated to 5.5 as soon as it is out...

Comment: If Ubuntu tells you the packages have been "kept back", run `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Running `php -a` starts 'Interactive mode', not 'Interactive shell'
Can I use 'Interactive shell' ?

Comment: This PPA now offers 5.5 which comes with an upgrade to Apache 2.4 that might break some installations. More details here:

http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2013/07/31/ubuntu-12-04-php-5-4-apache2-and-ppaondrejphp5/

Comment: This PPA is lacking the proper packages in order to install Virtualmin. libapache2-mod-fcgid : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed libapache2-mod-ruby : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed libapache2-svn : Depends: apache2.2-common but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Well, I used this and it worked so far as getting me PHP5.5 and Apache 2.4. My Apache is indeed messed up. Really having an adventure in trying to figure out WTF's Apache's issue is. It's like it no longer has php support, but the php mod is enabled. WTF?

Comment: Figured it out: When this installed Apache 2.4, my pre-existing site config was no longer functional. Turns out they added some new security setting to apache. I had to add "Require all granted" to my vhost's directory section (thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351167/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

Comment: I've done everything as it was written and still I'm getting 5.5, not 5.4 :(

Comment: Use `apt-get install software-properties-common` if `apt-get install python-software-properties` doesn't provide the `add-apt-repository` command.

Comment: As of Dec 12, 2016 this no longer works for PHP 5.5. The repository removed support for the 5.5 packages according to this tweet. https://twitter.com/debsuryorg/status/808284372356825088 How can I reliably install PHP 5.5.31 now after this?

Comment: For PHP 7 there are many extensions unavailable such as GD !

Comment: is PPA package support PHP 5.6 on ubuntu 18.04? when i try using it showing forbidden.

Answer (score 4):

It will take some time for PHP 5.4 packages to make their way into Ubuntu, as there are an awful lot of dependency checks to do. Ubuntu 12.04 is now in beta so I doubt they'll upgrade it to PHP 5.4 (although I have no official or inside knowledge of this) -- it probably won't appear until Ubuntu 12.10 in October this year. If you want it sooner than that, you'll either have to find a third-party package or learn to build it yourself from the source code.