# Downgrading LAMP's PHP?

Tags: server, php, lamp

i'm somewhat new to Ubuntu. I am a web developer, and I've been trying to install LAMP properly so I can test my creations.

Here's my issue, I use PHP 5.2.5 to program as I find it to be the superior version of PHP, others ma disagree at will lol. I believe LAMP comes with PHP 5.3 if not higher, how do I go about downgrading. I'm used to the windows environment where I can just download an executable.

Comment: What is it you don't like about 5.3?

Comment: Anything after 5.2.5 seems to have pointless errors, they become more buggy, and include pointless things that you could do in a few lines of a function. It seems pointless to upgrade after 5.2.5

Comment: [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/109404/582516)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have always preferred to download the individual components rather than a wrapper, and this has always worked out well for me.  The advantage is that if something isn't working, there is one less thing to get in the way.

However, if you really need an older version of PHP, you might find it to be too much trouble to get all the versions to work together; I don't know if the current versions of MySQL and Apache work with the old PHP version.

You could try something like this: [Bitnami Lampstack](http://bitnami.org/files/download/bitnami-lampstack-1.2-5-linux-installer.run), but I don't think it supports 64-bit.

Another option is [Oldapps xampp](http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php).  Oldapps.com would be good if you wanted to go the separate route also, as they have old versions of all the individual components.