# How do I install PHP-FPM 5.4 on 12.04?

Tags: php, php-fpm

I would like to install PHP 5.4 with FPM on a 12.04 virtual machine. The popular PPA solution for installing PHP 5.4 doesn't seem to include the php5-fpm package.

What's the best way to install this version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If your system is 32 bit (old computers):**

Go to [this thread](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/php5-fpm) and select the latest version. Then download the file there is on the Downloadable files section

**If your system is 64 bit (the most common by now):**

Go to [this thread](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/php5-fpm) and select the latest version. Then download the file there is on the Downloadable files section

---

**Installing PHP from terminal:**

Enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

---

**Compile your self:**

[In this web page](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) you will found the download link with the packages.

Then you have to [compile and install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file).

---

More information about [the LAMP installation on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Thank you, but it seems there only are PHP 5.3 packages listed there.

Comment: Have you tried with "sudo apt-get php4-fpm"?

Comment: I think you are overlooking that I want to install the 5.4 version, which has not trickled down yet in the official repositories.

Comment: @Gerry For the 5.4v you have to compile the source.

Comment: @Gerry see my answer below...  You can use my PPA, which mirrors my work I do on Debian packages.

Comment: @Gerry BTW I wonder while you have clicked on this anwer as 'answered' while it does not in fact help with your problem,

Answer (score 6):

I will (ab)use already answered question:
[How do I install PHP 5.4.0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0)

You could use a ppa to stay up-to-date with php. I use :

[https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)

It's now on 5.4. If you want use this ppa do this:

[ppa:ondrej/php5 [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you don't have add-apt-repository binary do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

*For more, see the already answered question mentioned in the top.*

Comment: Alright, this _does_ install php 5.4. However, this doesn't seem to solve how to get __php5-fpm__ in 5.4 flavor.

Comment: Simple `apt-get install php5-fpm` will install php5-fpm in 5.4 flavor.  What's output of `apt-cache policy php5-fpm`?

Comment: http://pastie.org/7732086 Please note that I have 11.04 and OP has 12.04. Could be also useful if someone pointed out the right way to install PHP-FPM 5.4 on 11.04. I've tried `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` already.

Comment: Natty is no longer supported.  I do build packages only for supported releases.

Comment: Had to pick the version specifically, i.e. `sudo apt-get install php5-common=5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1` then `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm=5.4.23-1+sury.org~precise+1` to install/upgrade php5-fpm to php 5.4. (Got the hint from @oerdnj asking the output of `apt-cache policy php5-fpm`.)