# Is there any repository for installing PHP 5.2.x on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, php

I would like to know if there is any repository I can add to install php5.2.9+ on Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Comment: Why 5.2.x? Why not the latest? Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-php-5-4-0

Comment: unfortunately its an external application to our organization and they require php version 5.2.9 to 5.2.x

Comment: @user136441 - Can you elaborate more on how you installed 5.2.x? Did you append the karmic repo to the current repo list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP 5.2 was sent to end of life in December of 2010, so while there's a small chance you might find a PPA or .deb file in some dark alley of the Internet, you're very likely going to have to compile it from source if you want it to run on Ubuntu 12.04. Additionally, it's possible you'll run into problems with dependencies (particularly if anything has changed their API), so keep that in mind.

That said, you can find the latest source for the PHP 5.2 series on [their GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/php-5.2.17) (I found the 5.2.17 tag for you), and compile it using `make`. [The PHP site also offers information on compiling PHP](http://php.net/git.php). The required versions will be different, but it's typically a "this version or greater" unless you get into major release differences (1.0 to 2.0, for example).

As a side note, it might be worth putting pressure on the people that maintain your external application to upgrade to at least the 5.3 series, or better yet, the 5.4 series. There have been a ton of bug fixes and security patches since then. Additionally, most tools don't support 5.2 anymore (which means you don't get things like Xdebug or PHPUnit without a fight, making maintaining an application of decent size and reasonable importance damn near impossible (I've been there)). The upgrade may not be something that can be done right away, thanks to changes between 5.2 and 5.3, but it generates customer demand and helps break down the delusion that a lot of companies have of "well, our userbase doesn't  want this, so we're not going to offer it" (even though the reason they don't demand it is because it was absent from the product and they found workarounds, nevermind the fact that if the product offered it, the customers would use it).

Comment: If you compile php from source you may need to read up on what options you wish to enable (it is a long list).

Comment: Only will compile php if i cant find a repo on the net. Tks for your help shauna

Comment: Used http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ added karmic repo and have php 5.2.10 installed.

Comment: @user136441 - Just fyi, you can answer your own question. So feel free to make that an answer and mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I had never done it on Ubuntu, but yes in **Debian Squeeze** using the respository of **Debian Lenny**.

As the packages of PHP are all from Debian I think that this tutorial will server for Ubuntu.

1. Edit the repository list.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add the next line to ther /etc/apt/sources.list:

   ```
   deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
   ```
3. Update the information of repos

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Edit the preferences of apt...

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/php.conf
   ```
5. Add the next conf:

   ```
   Package: php5*
   Pin: release a=oldstable
   Pin-Priority: 700

   Package: *
   Pin: release a=stable
   Pin-Priority: 600
   ```
6. Install
       sudo apt-get install php5 -t oldstable
7. Check that is the 5.2* version installed

   ```
   sudo dpkg -l | grep php5
   ```

I repeat... **not tested**... just what i do on Debian ...

Original source: http://www.gustavopilla.com/2012/01/21/php-5-2-en-debian-squeeze/

Comment: sudo apt-get install php5 -t oldstable 
And I got this
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16) but it is not going to be installed or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny16) but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file 'php.conf' in directory '/etc/apt/preferences.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who ends up here should consider [following this tutorial](http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-install-php-53-and-52-together-on-ubuntu-1204).

It explains in details how to compile and setup PHP 5.2 alongside the supported PHP version and how to use in only on the needed vhost.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Followed that tutorial can installed php 5.2.17 but many extensions are not installed even it was enabled.