# Php repository without suhosin

Tags: apt, repository, php

I don't really know how to or want to compile php from source, but i need php without suhosin. As you may know the main repository comes with suhosin patch. this is causing errors on my website and I need it gone. the attempts to disable built-in suhosin failed and the only reliable option i have is to install php from source.

Is there a repository that comes with php5 but without built-in suhosin patch, so i can just install php through apt-get and be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Seeing how suhosin has a very valid purpose, the first question here would be: Why does it cause problems? Usually errors thrown by suhosin would indicate errors with the code you're trying to run and as such you shouldn't really try to bypass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends whether you are also willing to bump PHP version to latest (5.4).  If the answer is yes, then I would suggest to follow:

[How do I install latest PHP in supported Ubuntu versions (like 5.4.x in Ubuntu 12.04)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1)

which doesn't include suhosin patch anymore, because suhosin is upstream-dead.

Also newer Ubuntu releases (those which contain php5 >= 5.4.0) doesn't include suhosin anymore.

But be warned that generally the problems you might have with suhosin won't go away and usually indicate some deeper problem withing the PHP (like memory leak, etc.).