# How to upgrade the php version from 5.3.x to 5.3.y?

Tags: upgrade, php, drupal

I just downloaded the development release of Drupal8 for testing purpose. When I try to install it shows the following error:

```
Your PHP installation is too old. Drupal requires at least PHP 5.3.10.
```

My current php version is 5.3.8. How do I make update only to php? Or do I need to update mysql also?

Comment: Please do not cross post with other stackexchange sites. Source code can be found here: http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: Why not update everything with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with xampp

Comment: @alvar: I tried that but no luck, still having same 5.3.8

Comment: @Rinzwind: I also tried the link you mentioned, no luck yet. It took almost 1hr and the xampp php version is still 5.3.8.

Comment: I would use Lamp if I was you. xamp is a piece of software not worth mentioning.

Comment: @Rinzwind: well.. I am stuck with xampp rightnow, not willing to change any sooner. So I'm still looking for solution to upgrade php. I really appreciate the help and I'm still looking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You could use a ppa to stay up-to-date with php.

```
 sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1)

Comment: I did everything as mentioned, after all the update and upgrade I'm getting same old PHP Version 5.3.8 as phpinfo output

Comment: @pown sudo apt-get install php5

Comment: I already have php5, just I need upgrade. Should I need to do apt-install again??

Comment: sudo apt-get remove php then install it again

Comment: check there links https://www.mellzamora.com/installing-php5-4-apache2-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-linux/ <> http://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu all the same