# Upgraded PHP on Ubuntu but old version still in use

Tags: php, 12.04

I just upgraded PHP to V5.4 on my laptop, using the technique described in this answer, [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1/109544#109544).

I did the same for my desktop a while back and it all worked fine.  On my laptop however the old version (5.3.10) is still showing at the CLI (php -v) and the SAPI (phpinfo()).  why is it so?

Presumably there is a config file (or two) that needs updating?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

EDIT: output of `dpkg -l '*php5*'` as requested: (sorry about the formatting)

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  libapache2-mod 5.3.10-1ubuntu server-side, HTML-embedded scripting languag
un  libapache2-mod <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5           5.3.10-1ubuntu server-side, HTML-embedded scripting languag
un  php5-cgi       <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5-cli       5.3.10-1ubuntu command-line interpreter for the php5 script
ii  php5-common    5.3.10-1ubuntu Common files for packages built from the php
ii  php5-curl      5.3.10-1ubuntu CURL module for php5
ii  php5-dev       5.3.10-1ubuntu Files for PHP5 module development
un  php5-fpm       <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5-gd        5.3.10-1ubuntu GD module for php5
ii  php5-gmp       5.3.10-1ubuntu GMP module for php5
un  php5-idn       <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-imap      <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5-intl      5.3.10-1ubuntu internationalisation module for php5
un  php5-json      <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-ldap      <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5-mcrypt    5.3.5-0ubuntu1 MCrypt module for php5
un  php5-mhash     <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5-mysql     5.3.10-1ubuntu MySQL module for php5
un  php5-mysqli    <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-mysqlnd   <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-pgsql     <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-sqlite    <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-sqlite3   <none>         (no description available)
un  php5-suhosin   <none>         (no description available)
ii  php5-xdebug    2.1.0-1        Xdebug Module for PHP 5
ii  php5-xmlrpc    5.3.10-1ubuntu XML-RPC module for php5
ii  php5-xsl       5.3.10-1ubuntu XSL module for php5
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Problem solved

Hi, Ubuntu suddenly decided it had numerous other updates to apply, including a kernel upgrade, so I let that happen and we now have v 5.4!  (The CLI is saying it can't load xdebug, but I've seen this before and should be able to sort it out.  If I can't I'll raise another question).

Comment: Did you restart apache, or the web server you are running?

Comment: Yep, restarted the laptop.

Comment: please add output of: dpkg -l '\*php5\*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See last edit above.  Basically, Ubuntu needed to install some updates, and once this had happened, php 5.4 was in use.

Comment: Please flag the question as answered (You always need to do apt-get update && apt-get (dist-)upgrade).  There should be a php5-xcache package in my PHP PPA prepared for PHP5.4 as well, so it might be a matter of installing php5-xcache (apt-get install php5-xcache).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding this:

```
LoadFile "d:/Apache24/php/php-5.6.29/php5ts.dll"
```

in `httpd.conf`

fixed it for me

Answer (score -2):

Since you were using ubuntu, you could've just done an update using aptitude or apt-get. Eitherway, you need to update httpd.conf and make sure that  php5_module points to the place where your new php is.

`LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`

The reason why it still points to an older version of php might be due to your computer having multiple copies of php.