# Custom install of PHP

Tags: 13.04, php

I have always used the code below to install my PHP environment:

```
sudo apt-get install -qqy php5 sqlite php5-gd php5-sqlite libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql php5-intl php5-curl
```

However I can no longer do this as the latest version of PHP in Ubuntu 13.04 is PHP 5.4.9.  This version has the known bug #63379 that basically destroys the logout handler from the Symfony Security Component.

I know I've got two options: install via adding a custom PPA (this post has all the details on that: [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1)) or via script.

Seeing as this is needed for a server that my company uses I simply won't be prepared to add these private PPAs due to security risks.  But rather I would like to create a script to install any version of PHP *and* the above packages (sqlite, curl, etc) I normally install in one easy step via apt-get install.

Does anybody have a custom script that covers all the above mentioned packages?  Also is there anything else I should watch out for via the script method for installing PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of trust, I'd struggle to find a PPA I trusted more than [Ondřej Surý's PHP PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5). He's on a lot of official packaging teams. If he *wanted* to sneak something onto your system, he wouldn't need to resort to a PPA to do it.

I'd be more concerned with the underlying stability of PHP but if you're building from source, you're likely going to hit those problems by yourself.

Comment: You bring a good point about "trust" in the person.  He does indeed  sound very trustworthy.  I wasn't too sure how to do a "check the credentials of developer" so thanks for the link.