# Problems with installation from ppa:ondrej

Tags: server, ppa, php

The server is running Lucid and I am trying to upgrade the PHP to 5.5 stable.

I followed the intructions on this question: [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1)

```
root@32772-201711:~# add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpZCjHpD/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpZCjHpD/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpZCjHpD/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for OndÅej SurÃ½" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Then I ran `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade`, and just for overkill, I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade`. These last 2 commands both state that my system is up to date.

However, when I execute `php -v`, I still see `5.3.2-1ubuntu4.20`.

My PHP is not upgrading to PHP5.5 as expected

What am I missing in order to upgrade the PHP to the version offered by the PPA?

Answer (score 5):

There's no PHP 5.5 packages for Lucid, since it would require too much work (and forking the repository, etc...) that I don't have time for (in my free time).

You can either stick with PHP 5.4 in ppa:ondrej/oldstable or upgrade to precise and use the Apache 2.4/PHP 5.5 repository.

I am open to preparing PHP 5.5 for Lucid as a contracted work, but it won't happen in my free time, since I am trying to save it for my family. And preparing PHP 5.5 for Lucid (e.g. Apache 2.2) would take something like 2-5 days.

Comment: +1 for enthusiasm, time management and honesty.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the mentioned PPA does not contain builds for Lucid, it only contains builds for the latest versions of Ubuntu.

You may send a message to the PPA maintainer asking for a Lucid (10.04) version for this PPA. Please keep in mind that this may not be possible due to dependency issues.

EDIT: I just saw that on the link that you mentioned https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable is specified, where it contains Lucid builds!

In order to install this PPA to your system, first of all please remove the old ppa from your system and then run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```