# phpmyadmin not longer working after updating to php5.5 on LTS12.04

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

After i upgrade to PHP5.5 like in this thread

[How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1)

my phpmyadmin is not working after i try to access to over my apache2 webinterface.

> ERROR 404 PAGE NOT FOUND

has anyone a solution for this Problem?

remove and try to install it new was no success

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed phpmyadmin with apt - reconfigure it from terminal:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

See more at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=812971

If necessary - check out for existing config at /etc/apache2/conf-enabled - there should be phpmyadmin.conf symlink.

or

you can install it manually - from http://www.phpmyadmin.net - download and unpack in web root directory. If you already tried to install phpmuadmin with apt - avoid using phpmyadmin as directory name, use padmin, for example. Then point to yoursite.net/padmin.

Comment: >/etc/apache2/conf-enabled - there should be phpmyadmin.conf this file is missing

Comment: Please try to reconfigure phpmyadmin - sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin