# apache broke after upgrading

Tags: server, upgrade, apache2, php, apache2.4

I tried to upgrade my php version with the help of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1/109544?newreg=482f72bd5522486981e94dbee728eef6) and somehow the apache version also upgraded. After this upgrade I got a lot of errors obviously and I managed to solve lots of them except this one

> apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authmysql.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/modauthmysql.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/modauth_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The module doesn't exist as I checked. How can I solve this? I tried to google all the way but I can't seem to find a correct answer.

Any help would be awesome :) Thanks in advance guys!

*edit* I think this problem occurs because of iredmail that depends on that module. Could this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [libapache2-mod-auth-mysql](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libapache2-mod-auth-mysql&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).