# unable to install apache2 on precise

Tags: apt, apache2, dpkg, php, regex

## Below is the error while running the command:

```
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get install apache2*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2.conf
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'apache2.conf'
root@mycompanyname:~#
```

Background:

Wanted to update php5.3 (5.3 PHP = 7.43 INR) to php5.5 (5.5 PHP = 7.72 INR) to do this followed steps given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1).

After this apache2 stopped detecting php itself.

After lot of troubleshooting we removed php and apache2 using below commands:

```
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get purge apache2*
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get purge php*
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get autoremove
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get autoclean
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get clean
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get remove
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get purge
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get install
root@mycompanyname:~# dpkg -a -configure
```

after all this we tried to reinstall apache2 and started getting that error:

Just for reference [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10140172/) is the sources.list file for apt.

We are not facing any issues while using below commands:

```
root@mycompanyname:~# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Please help! thanks in advance.

Comment: Try without the `*`. Or quote it: `'apache2*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 apt-get install apache2*
```

Should just be

```
 apt-get install apache2
```

Apt will suggest some extra packages to install at that point. Read through them and decide if want/need, but I usually only install

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 is working in my system so try follow this:

Please remove already you installed apache2 and php5.

Now try to a fresh installation.

You add source code to apt sources list.
gedit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to add following codes:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu precise main           
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu precise main  

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu precise main   
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu precise main
```

Save and update it.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install apache, php5 and mysql also:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server
```

After installed you get php5.5 and apache2.4 versions.

Comment: It would be better to do `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5` instead of manually editing `sources.list`.

Comment: I try to add repository in terminal but its not added, thats only i suggested him to manually editing sources list.

Comment: That might be some problem with your system, but it is not good advice in general.

Comment: Every packages are loaded from source list then how to get problem ?