# Downgrade PHP 5.6 to PHP 5.5

Tags: php

I installed Ubuntu 15.04, but I need to use PHP 5.5 and in 15.04 the standard is PHP 5.6

I added the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

But when I tried to install, I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 

    php5-mcrypt : Depends: phpapi-20121212 Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1) 
but 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 is to be installed
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: What do you mean you try to install? what is the command you used?

Comment: Is there a reason that you need PHP 5.5 and not PHP 5.6?

Comment: Also, note that `php5-mcrypt` is in the repos, and, depending on the list of modules you need, you might not need to use a PPA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install different or more recent PHP versions in supported Ubuntu releases? (like 5.5.x in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-or-more-recent-php-versions-in-supported-ubuntu-relea)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need PHP 5.5, than install this version with this command (for version `5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1`) and check the correct version [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75):

```
sudo apt-get install php5=5.5.24+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
```

and set the package on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold php5
```

Otherwise you'll get in the next update again version 5.6

Answer (score 0):

The PPA maintainer has a [separate PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6) for use with PHP 5.6. I recommend that you use this PPA instead of downgrading to PHP 5.5

Comment: OP said: "... but I need to use PHP 5.5 ..."

Comment: My interpretation is that he wants to use PHP 5.5 because that PPA is using PHP 5.5. If he really does have a hard requirement on PHP 5.5, then my answer is invalid.

Comment: We should ask him.