# How to update PHP to the newest version(5.5) on LAMPP Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: updates, php, mysql, lamp

I have installed LAMPP about a year ago, I remember that it was very easy because I just had to download a tar.gz file and extracted it to the `/opt/` folder it always worked great. Now I want to upgrade from PHP `5.4` to the `5.5` version. I do I update only Php without having to re-install LAMPP again?

Comment: Questions about EOL releases are off-topic, so I voted to close this question. However, assuming that you meant "Now I want to upgrade from PHP `5.4` to the `5.5` version." have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1). If you didn't, also consider updating to `PHP 5`, since `PHP 4` is EOL since about 7 years

Comment: @kos my mistake, I did mean php 5.4 and 5.5

Comment: Update to 15.04 and you'll also get a newer php ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind You also only get supported until the end of 2015. I wouldn't suggest release upgrades for servers as the first step just to upgrade one package.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for the advise, I will try to do it, I am just afraid of loosing my information since I am using a dual boot that I installed with Wubi

Comment: @oli sure but he is using 12.10 anyways so is not using a LTS anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Just read the title to the end and noticed you're on 12.10! Upgrade! Upgrade immediately! You are literally *years* behind on security updates.

Actually, it's probably easier to just do a fresh install of 14.04 (a LTS version, see below) than upgrading to 13.04 (dead), 13.10 (dead) and then to 14.04. And not meaning to scare you, but there have been some pretty serious security issues that you haven't been protected against; your install could already be exploited.

The below was written assuming you were using 14.04.

---

For standard PHP installations, I would recommend just hopping to the `ondrej/php5` PPA. This is a repository maintained by Ondřej Surý (a Debian PHP packager) and this PPA tracks the Debian PHP team's work. It should be as good as what you get from Ubuntu directly.

```
sudo apt install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5
```

That said, if you're using LAMPP, all bets are off. LAMPP is a completely unneccessary and separate packaging of components that I would ***never*** suggest be used for production. Use Ubuntu's (or Ondřej's) version. It's maintained and updated in a predictable way.

There's also a comment on your question that you upgrade to a later release of Ubuntu. If you're on 14.10, sure that dies in July, but if you're on 14.04, well, 14.04 is a Long Term Support release and is maintained up to 2019. 15.04 barely gets you to 2016. That means fewer upgrades, less maintenance for you, and a lot less testing.

So my final suggestion:

- <strike>Stay on</strike> Install an LTS release
- Install the *proper* LAMP stack that Ubuntu ships
- Use Ondřej's PPA to hop to the latest stable PHP version (5.5 now).

Comment: So I have followed the steps above to install php5 from ondrej ppa, but when I enter the `sudo apt-get install php5` it again installs php5.4.6 Could this be because I am still using Ubuntu12.10?

Comment: `Get:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main php5-common amd64 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.8`

Comment: That above, is the first output I get after I run apt-get install

Comment: @Yuran. Yes. The PPA only supports supported releases (which you haven't been on for a long time). Upgrade.