# Easiest way to update Apache, MySQL & PHP on VPS

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, php, mysql

I purchased a new VPS from bluehost they provided me old version of PHP that's not supporting my website and Its been 1 Week bluehost technical support team refused to do that they are making excuses.

My ubuntu version is 12.04.5 LTS

I want to update Apache,MySQL and PHP with their latest version and all dependencies and necessary extensions that are commonly used on website.

I know that some people think that my Question is duplicate of other questions.

I am asking that what I have to do for upgrading Apache, MySQL and PHP for example: I have to remove all these three before upgrading on server ?

My problem is how can i upgrade Apache, MySQL and PHP???

Please explain step by step

Comment: That's a pretty extensive tutorial you are asking for. I'm recommending closing as "too broad".

Comment: I believe this also provides the newest version of apache as well.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I am not asking for tutorial, I am asking for your help bro

Comment: @mchid My Question is not duplicate

Comment: @mchid I will try this

Comment: right now i am reading that link you provided me

Comment: @mchid I mean latest version of Apache, MySQL and PHP available for ubuntu 12.04.5 from manufacturers

Comment: @mchid I looked on PHP official site they official announced Current Stable PHP version is  5.6.14

Comment: @mchid I think that all latest version of Apache, MySQL and PHP supports ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: Okay, then I believe you should follow the instructions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you begin, you should know that ppas are not officially supported. ppas are provided by members of the community. As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-latest-php-in-supported-ubuntu-versions-like-5-4-x-in-ubuntu-1), you should [visit this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) before you begin.

Although, it should be noted that this particular ppa is used by many people, if you Google "php5 ppa" you will see many tutorials reference this.

To install the newer versions and to add the ppa for php version 5.6 and mysql 5.6 and the newer version of apache as well, run the following commands and please post any errors:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

For more info: [visit here for info on the php5 ppa and a list of the packages added by the ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6/+index?batch=75)

Also: [visit here for more info on the mysql ppa and a full list of the added packages](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6/+index?batch=75)

Comment: what about apache

Comment: latest version of apache is 2.4

Comment: I believe it is provided by the php5 ppa https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6/+index?batch=75

Comment: @shawn_parker then you need to run `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties` first

Comment: When i run this command from ssh as root user 

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`

 or

 `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` 

its giving me error 

    -bash: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: I am currently installing python-software-properties.

Comment: updation process has started.

Comment: I know that bro ...

Comment: Problem occur bro

Comment: when i run this command: `sudo apt-get upgrade` its giving me this output:

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libjson0:i386 mysql-server openssl php5-cgi
  php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
  php5-sqlite php5-xsl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.`

Comment: @shawn_parker You can run `sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libjson0:i386 mysql-server openssl php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-sqlite php5-xsl` to upgrade that stuff.

Comment: after this output, I run this command `sudo apt-get install php5` then its give long output but i giving you last few lines

Comment: `12 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 4 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4931 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
`

Comment: after pressing `y`

it's give me long output but i am giving you last few lines

Comment: what you r saying bro??

Comment: after running this command `sudo apt-get upgrade` it asked me to do you want to keep the old version of software, I pressed n

Comment: after that suddenly it stopped

Comment: i restarted my vps server and run all the commands but it didn't asked me do you want to keep old software

Comment: When i pressed **n**  it did not did any process

Comment: bro should i install teamviewer or somekind of window sharing software

Comment: i check that it did not uninstall any software

Comment: first time i run **apt-get upgrade** it asked me do you want to keep old software then i pressed **n** it did some process but it didn't uninstall any software

Comment: now when i run  **apt-get upgrade** its giving me this output:

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done The following packages have been kept back: apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 libjson0:i386 mysql-server openssl php5-cgi php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-gd php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-sqlite php5-xsl 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.`

Comment: only first it asked do you want to keep old software... now its not asking

Comment: **apt-get-install php5**
`12 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 4 to remove and 3 not upgraded. Need to get 14.3 MB of archives. After this operation, 4931 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y`

Comment: what packages are listed to remove

Comment: after pressing **y** its stopped with some errors on the bottom :

Comment: `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: bro currently i am talking to **bluehost** support

Comment: then run `apt-get remove apache2.2-common` however,  don't press y if it says it will remove a bunch of packages. If it only lists one or two packages to remove, then press **y**

Comment: You wanted version 2.4 anyhow and you can't have 2.2 and 2.4 installed on the same system.

Comment: bro wait lets check what **bluehost** technical team says.

Comment: r u there????????????????

Comment: @shawn_parker yep, what's up?

Comment: **bluehost** support team saying our technical team will do that... i don't know when they do

Comment: what should i do now ???

Comment: @shawn_parker you just need to uninstall or remove apache2.2-common before you can install php5. After you run: `apt-get remove apache2.2-common` you can run `apt-get install php5` and you should not see the same error.

Comment: Ok bro .. i am starting again whole process from beginning

Comment: You still need to remove `apache2.2-common`

Comment: yes i will remove apache2.2-common

Comment: bro when i run this command `apt-get remove apache2.2-common` its giving me same error just i mentioned abvoe

Comment: `dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz', which is also in package apache2.2-common 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10
dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-bin_2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: @shawn_parker okay, run `apt-get clean` and then: `dpkg -r apache2.2-common` then run: `apt-get update` and finally: `apt-get install php5`

Comment: @shawn_parker you see, when apt-get doesn't work, we can use dpkg to remove apache2.2common instead. Once that is done, you should be able to  proceed without error.

Comment: when i run `dpkg -r apache2.2-common` it give me this output

Comment: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of apache2.2-common:
 libapache2-mod-php5 depends on apache2.2-common.
 apache2 depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10); however:
  Package apache2.2-common is to be removed.
 apache2-mpm-prefork depends on apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.10).
 libapache2-mod-python depends on apache2.2-common.
dpkg: error processing apache2.2-common (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2.2-common
`

Comment: @shawn_parker okay, run: `dpkg -r libapache2-mod-php5` then: `dpkg -r apache2-mpm-prefork` and: `dpkg -r libapache2-mod-python` and finally: `dpkg -r apache2.2-common`

Comment: bro finally **bluehost** technical team doing upgradation........

Comment: if its get updated i will tell you and then i will accept your answer as solution

Comment: you just about had it, it's messy but there is light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: yeah bro.. I want to say that I never met a person like you, you are so kind.. Thanking you sooo muchhh for giving me your precious time bro