# How to install zpanel 10.1.1 for Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server

How to install zpanel 10.1.1 for Ubuntu server 16.04?

I tried:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/beta/Ubuntu-14_04-LTS/ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh
sudo bash ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh
```

but received message:

```
Sorry, this installer only supports the installation of ZPanel on Ubuntu 14.04.
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for ZPanel officially ended in 2014 when it was reported that it would [only be supported for HostWinds customers](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1449197).

It was subsequently forked by some of the original developers to create [Sentora](http://www.sentora.org/).  They even have a [forum for ZPanel](http://forums.sentora.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=52) and there is some support there.

At this point, there have been major releases of Sentora (now version 1.0.3), but they warn that php7 is not yet supported due to a bottleneck with the development of suhosin (a type of jailshell mechanism).  This makes installing on Ubuntu 18.04, where php7 is the default, difficult but still technically possible.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported) for installing php 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I tried to download the .sh file itself than I edited it so it does not check for the requierements, first it seemed it is running correctly but than I saw that there were lots of errors while trying to install packages. Go with another alternative to ZPanel.