# How to install an older minor version of PHP7.0

Tags: 14.04, php, ppa

I'm having a issue with PHP7.0 v 7.0.21 and the MSSQL driver. 
Every thing was working fine in 7.0.18. 
The only version I see in the official PPA is 7.0.21.
It's possible to install this specific older release version (18) of PHP instead of the default (21)?
I'm running Ubuntu Trusty

Regards
Luis

Comment: I've never used PHP, but this may be useful: [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/109404/301745)

Comment: Thx wjandrea. This article is about choose between versions 5.6 7.0 or 7.1. What I need is to install an old minor version of the 7.0 branch.

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't be more helpful. BTW, you may want to clarify that you're looking for an older release version (18), not minor version (0).