# Removing PHP 7.2, and installing PHP 5.6

Tags: apt, software-installation, php, ppa

I'm a new Linux user, and I'm using a web server with a software that requires PHP 5.6, creating an incompatibility issue that I have been trying to solve for at least two days now. I read up a bunch of threads here on it, but none of them really solved the issue. The Linux version I'm at is 18.04.

So, what I tried so far:

- To uninstall PHP 7.2 using `sudo apt-get purge php7.0-common`
- To disable the proxy using `sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi proxy` (it returns that the proxy is already disabled)
- To install PHP 5.6 using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` or `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2`, it installs it
- After using `sudo apt-get update`, and using this `sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0`, I get the error:

  - I used [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported) suggested on the comments, and the php5-compat helped, now at least when I try to unmount/mount (or whatever it's called) I don't get a "php5.6 module doesn't exist" anymore, and now if I do `sudo apt-cache search php5.6 --names-only` I get the list of packages for the first time.

Since I got that part done now, I'll consider it as done and see with the Oxwall people about their requirements. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: for any package you can search by: `apt-cache search php5.6` as it does not return anything. It means there is no such package.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: Yeah, I found that thread before, and tried that @user535733, no luck. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: 18.04, @ThomasWard. I added it to the thread. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`? Thanks.