# How can I install php5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 for box billing?

Tags: php, php-fpm

I want to install boxbilling which runs php5.
Ubuntu 16.04 currently has php 7.2

What is the procedure for doing this? (the parent server has other Apache websites on it that run php7 so I don't want to disable or remove php7).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported)

Comment: instead of saying possible duplicate, how about answering the question? Clearly I am having problems that other "possible duplicates" have failed to successfully help with.

Comment: In that case, please [edit] your question and tell what exactly you tried and what was the result. You should post commands and their full output in your question’s body. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu. Please upgrade to a supported release. See https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/