# How to install php5 alongside existing php7 which is installed using xampp?

Tags: php, lamp, xampp, php7

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 unity 64 bit.

For php7 I have xampp installed, for php5, I cannot have xampp, it will override php7.

I need to temporarily install php5, how to do that? And how to switch back and fourth between them? Do I need to remove xampp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install different (upgrade or downgrade) PHP version in still supported Ubuntu release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported)

Comment: @KristopherIves the difference is, php7 is installed using xampp, so different php.ini location